# KnockoutJS custom binding firing multiple times

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to show a notification DIV using acustom binding, while also adjusting that DIV's CSS and HTML via 2 observables.

The ***problem*** is that when I change value of those 2 observables, it also fires the custom binding as well for some reason.

**Template:**

```
<div class="alert top-alert" data-bind="fade: topMessageShow, css: topMessageType, html: topMessage"></div>
```

**Custom Handler:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fade = {
  update: function resolveFade(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable( valueAccessor() )) {
      $(element).hide().delay(300).fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      // fade out the notification and reset it
      $(element).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        // reset those 2 observables that set class and HTML of the notification DIV
        MyClass.topMessageType('');
        MyClass.topMessage('');
      });
    }
  }
};
```

**Triggering Code:**

```
MyClass.topMessageType('alert-info');
MyClass.topMessage(msg);
MyClass.topMessageShow(true);
```

---

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/UrxXF/1/

Comment: I *think* your problem is with the other bindings to observables. They all become part of the `allBindingsAccessor` and changing them *could* require your binding to be reevaluated, so knockout calls it again. To fix the problem you could check the visibility and/or animation status of the element before fading in/out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to the fact that all bindings fire together on a single element.  Here is a post that describes the current behavior: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html.  This is actually changing in KO 3.0 where bindings are maintained independently on an element.

One choice that you could use for now is to set up your own `computed` in the `init` function like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fade = {
  init: function resolveFade(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      ko.computed({
         read: function() {
             /your logic goes here
         },
         disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
      });
  }
};
```

With this technique you are simulating the `update` function, but allowing it to act independently from the other bindings on the element.  The only minor drawback is that you would currently not get any dependencies from observables that are unwrapped in the binding string (like `fade: topMessageShow()` rather than `fade: topMessageShow`).

Comment: this seems to do the trick, thank you! any info about when KO 3.0 should be coming out?

Comment: we should have a beta out in the next month along with a release of KO 2.3.